# how to insert value checkbox on off without submit button on laravel

Tags: html, mysql, laravel

I have a checkboxes, and want to submit the value of the checkbox to database. I would prefer not to have a submit button,

```
<label>OFF<input type="checkbox" checked><span class="lever"></span>ON</label>
```

[image]

Comment: Use AJAX, e.g AngularJS or jQuery to trigger a POST action when a mouse event has been triggered. Unfortunately, we can't help you write this code, you'll have to figure it out but do post back if you run into any trouble! And Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#aksi').change(function() {
  var returnVal = confirm("Are you sure?"); 
        if(returnVal){
          postToServer($(this).prop("checked"))
        }else{
          $(this).prop("checked", !$(this).is(":checked"));
        }       
    });
});

function postToServer(state){
    let value = (state) ? 1 : 0;
    alert('Posted Value: ' + value);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://your-server.com/update/aski",
      data: {"aski":value},
      success: function(response){
     //handle response
      }
    });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>OFF<input type="checkbox" id="aksi" checked><span class="lever"></span>ON</label>
```

Comment: you just change `http://your-server.com/update/aski` with your laravel resource route and add other fields in `data: {"aski":value}`